# Wordpress loop through posts and check if posts are in same category

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible in wordpress to loop through posts and then if the next post is not in the same category then do something.

So within the loop of each post I'd need to get the cateogry or categories the post is in.

Then some how store and compare it to the next post in the the loop.

Comment: What are you doing the comparison for? Like...what are you using the true/false for?

Comment: @rnevius I am using woocommerce but the client doesn't want the user to be able to order a product from two different categories. For example they carn't order a holiday trip and a day trip but can order multiple day trips. Therefore if the post category doesn't match the previous posts category then an error message.

Answer (score 0):

My strategy would be to set a check array for the previous categories and then compare each time.

So inside the loop you can do a check for the current categories

e.g.

```
//set a check array 
$previous_categories = array();

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $the_query->the_post();
    // get the categories for this post
    $current_categories = get_the_category();

    // set up a temp array to change the previous_categories array when we have finished
    $tmp_categories = array();

    // now iterate through the categories and see if it is in the previous post
    if($categories){
       foreach($categories as $category) {
          // do the check
          if (in_array($category->term_id,$previous_categories)){
              // then its in the previous and you do your thing
          }

          // add the current id to the temp array
          $tmp_categories[] = $category->term_id;
       }
       // now we can set for the next post
       $previous_categories = $tmp_categories;

    } else {
        // there were no categories for this post so it cant match
        // but we do need to initialise the previous_categories array
        $previous_categories = array();
    }

}
```

I think that should do it for you